# How can I avoid using a lot of variables?

Tags: java, variables

I would like to create a simple program that would output the atomic mass of any element entered. I am taking a Java course that I recently started so I don't know how to avoid using over 100 variables each with the elements atomic mass.

Also how could I get a `if` statement to use the name input from the user (which I know how to store in a string) and match it with one of the elements, in order to output the element's mass (corresponding to method used to store the multiple elements).

How can I condense this example code:

```
int carbon = 12;
int oxygen = 16;
int hydrogen = 1;
int sulfur = 32;
etc....
```

Comment: This is a prime example of where you'd use classes to hold together data that logically belongs as part of a like concept. For example, you'd not use ints to represent your atoms, but rather the Atom class that has an atomicNumber, an atomicWeight, etc...

Comment: I think this is a prime example of where one would be tempted to define a class but shouldn't.

Comment: Martin, I'm curious to know why you think a class would be not advantageous here?  Is it because he is looking only to display the mass and not many characteristics?

Comment: Regarding your second question, if  I'm understanding you correctly, you want to essentially map element names to characteristics (mass, in this case). In which case you will want to look into the Map interface. This allows you to, well, create a mapping of objects :-). You could then do map.put(elementName, elementCharacteristics); and the converse, map.get(elementName); For more information on maps, see the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: @DanC When to define a class is subjective. In this case, I would consider classes to be premature optimization, and unnecessary indirection.  The user specifies that they only need to store a collection of pairs, the name of the element and the atomic weight.  Simple Java types (Map, String, int) are sufficient.  The user didn't specify that they want to extend this in the future.  Thus, no need for a class, in my opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like your first step is to learn about the Map data structure.  You can use it to associate the string names to integer values and then look them back up later.

```
Map<String, Integer> elements = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
elements.put("CARBON", 12);
elements.put("OXYGEN", 16);
//etc
```

Then if you have some input you can look up the number.

```
String userInput = scanner.next(); // or however you're getting input

Integer atomicWeight = elements.get(userInput.toUpper());
if (atomicWeight == null) //print element not found etc
```

Then once you have the program down and working you can learn about whatever technology is appropriate for loading the reference data from outside of the source code, whether that's a file or a database or a webservice or whatever.

Comment: I would recommend storing your data in a file, then reading from the file into a Map<?,?> type.  Then you can use your data.  The file can be XML, or a simple CSV format.

Comment: Of course, I just find it good to answer one question at a time and let the guy learn rather than bury him in information :)

Comment: ah, beat me to it, yep, a hashmap is the way to go for just these two bits of info. If he is new to java he will learn about files and classes later on and be able to improve.

Comment: @Affe and feldoh  You may both be right.  Perhaps, the person asking the question doesn't know how to read from files.

Comment: And hashmaps and files are probably the wrong constructs for static data like this.  the periodic table has changed only 5 times in the last 12 years, which is why i consider it static data.  For something with a present # of instances with static properties, it's perfect fodder for an enum.  That's the simplest solution with the least overhead IMHO.

Comment: That sounds like 5 times more than I want to have to explain to a product manager why I have to distribute a binary patch instead of run an update query or tell the customer which text file to edit :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd likely define an enum if confronted with this problem.

```
public enum Elements
{
    HYDROGEN(1),
    ...
    UNOBTANIUM(666);

    public final int atomicWeight;


    Elements(int atomicWeight)
    {
       this.atomicWeight = atomicWeight;
    }
}
```

then to get the right element it's

```
String name = ...// from user input
Elements e = Elements.valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the atomic mass of the elements is not going to change at any point in your app, you should define them as final:

```
public class AtomicMass {
    public static final int CARBON = 12;
    public static final int OXYGEN = 16;
    ...
}
```

...or, you could use an enum:

```
public static enum Element {
    carbon(12),
    oxygen(16),
    hydrogen(1),
    sulfur(32);

    private int atomicMass;

    private Element( int mass ) {
        this.atomicMass = mass;
    }
}
```

If you order your elements sequentially (and add an UNKNOWN for 0) you wouldn't even need to explicitly provide the mass.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an enum as some have suggested, though i'd do it a little different.  Maps have lots of overhead, and since your data is not dynamic it's not a great fit.  Atomic mass should be a decimal value (double or BigDecimal depending on what you're using it for), not an int

```
public enum AtomicElement {
    HYDROGEN(1.00794),
        HELIUM(4.002602),
        ...;

    private double atomicMass;

    private AtomicElement (double atomicMass) {
        this.atomicMass = atomicMass;
    }

    public int getAtomicNumber() {
        return ordinal();
    }

    public double getAtomicMass() {
        return atomicMass;
    }

    public static AtomicElement forAtomicNumber(int atomicNumber) {
         return AtomicElement.values()[atomicNumber];
    }

    public static AtomicElement forElementName(String elementName) {
         return AtomicElement.valueOf(elementName);
    }

}
```

Then you can search by atomic number or element name

```
   AtomicElement.forAtomicNumber(2);
   AtomicElement.forElementName("CARBON");
```

This does however assume you're going to represent the entire periodic table with no gaps in the data, since it's using the ordinal() value as the atomic number.  If you want gaps, you'll have to have an int field for the atomic number and your "forAtomicNumber" function will have to cycle through the "values()" to find the one with the given number.

You could even extend this if you wanted to include known isotopes, etc... if your requirements dictate that.

Answer (score 0):

I like to group related data into arrays or arrayLists.

```
String[] elements = new String[# of elements in table];
```

Based on the position of the element you can have the atomic number.

Then I would loop through them to find any element or fill the array.
You can look into Java Scanner class to get input from user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called `Element` that contains attributes like name, atomic number, etc. Each element will correspond to an instance of `Element`. You can then put all the `Elements`s in several maps, keyed by name, atomic number, etc. Use a factory class to instantiate and initialize the maps, and provide lookup methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just want to only have 1 variable to store all the elements and their masses in which case I would recommend a HashMap. It will not really save on code lines but will let you do number 2 pretty easily. HashMaps store a set of key-value pairs and you can get the value if you have the key so this would create the list:

```
//Declare a new hashmap and initialize it
HashMap<String, Integer> elements = new HashMap<>();

//Add element information
elements.put("CARBON", 12);
elements.put("OXYGEN", 16);
elements.put("HYDROGEN", 1);
elements.put("SULFUR", 32);
```

Then for example to get user input from a dialog box and print the result to command line  you do something like this:

```
//Collect user input and convert it to all upper case (in real life you would validate this)
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter an element name").toUpperCase();

//If element name exists in hashmap print its atomic weight
if(elements.containsKey(input.toUpperCase())){
    System.out.println("Atomic Weight: " + elements.get(input));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in a file

```
Element, Weight
oxygen = 16
carbon, 12
.
.
.
```

Pseudocode:

```
//Read data file into a `Map<String, int>`
//Get user input
//Access map
//Output
```